# boost regex_search cannot find the first match

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

```
boost::regex re("(abc)(.*?)");
boost::smatch m;
std::string str = "abcdlogin";
boost::regex_search(str, m, re);
```

I found m[1].first is "abcdlogin", m[1].second is "dlogin".

But I think is m[1].first should be "abc"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html):

> **m[n].first**: For all integers n < m.size(), the start of the sequence
>   that matched sub-expression n. Alternatively, if sub-expression n did
>   not participate in the match, then last.
>
> **m[n].second**: For all integers n < m.size(), the end of the sequence
>   that matched sub-expression n. Alternatively, if sub-expression n did
>   not participate in the match, then last.

Note how they are **iterators** into the matching sub-expression.
In your example, if you want a string with `"abc"`, you can construct a string like this: `std::string s(m[1].first, m[1].second);`.